# Setup iOS project to obfuscate with iXGuard 4.6 version

Tags: ios, obfuscation, xcode14, ixguard

The iOS project was setup to be obfuscated with iXGuard. So, with iXGuard <4.6 version (e.g. 4.5.1) and XCode <14 version, everything works fine, the binary was obfuscated successfully - no issue.

After upgrading to XCode 14 and iXGuard 4.6 versions, several issues appeared. Some unexpected issues/crashes appeared when trying obfuscated binary.

Here are some warnings reported during obfuscation:

*[warning] Failed to resymbolicate: No symbol map for bundle with UUID: xxx ("", arm64). Please refer to the manual to resolve this. (in_cannot_resymbolicate:2388569471)
[warning] Output consistency verification failed. Failed to verify MachO at: "". Found inconsistencies:
appID: 'com.xxx' != ''
Architecture: arm64
ncmds
(dri_model_consistency:3974536933)
[warning] ========== Binary name: xxx ==========
[warning] Provided input was built for older Xcode version 'Xcode 12.5' (vers_older_xcode:838522947) [x477]*

So, if anybody had similar issue and could solve the iXGuard 4.6 plus XCode 14  configuration, please share with the experience. Thanks in advance!